Internal`MRealToString Gives Scientific Output From Large Inputs. How To Stop This?
The undocumented Internal`MRealToString works just fine for reals up to 999999. For anything over it outputs scientific notation. I don't need scientific, I need simple decimal.
Internal`MRealToString[1.]






Internal`MRealToString[1000000.]


1.*^6

I need the latter to output 1000000.
How do I do that?

UPD. I am exporting over 3,000,000 reals into string, so performance is really important to me. That's why I'm using Internal'MRealToString instead of ToString.


Why are you using undocumented functions, which can have "unexplained" behaviour and change at any time, instead of relying on the documented functions?

I guess I'm really strange :)

if it is just for display purposes, you could try e = Internal``MRealToString[1000000.]; DecimalForm[ToExpression[e]]   screen shot  https://i.sstatic.net/65FLFb6B.png but why how it displays on the screen is important?

No I need to output to a file, as fast as possible.

then You can try e = 1000000.; ToString[DecimalForm[e]] and see the performance difference between this and MRealToString.  Try this on say 1000 real numbers, and compare. Unless the difference in timing is huge, I would not worry about it.

@Domen - for better or worse, this community does really like undocumented functionality just based on the popularity of this question

A combination of ToString and DecimalForm works (and works quickly),
In[17]:= ToString[DecimalForm[1000000.]]

Out[17]= "1000000."

